# Type Mismatch in Scala

Tags: scala, types, mismatch

I'm having type mismatch in the end line of code

```
 def balance(chars: List[Char]): Boolean = {

 def f(chars: List[Char], count: Int) :Boolean= 
  if(chars.isEmpty) {(count==0)}

      else if (chars.head == '(') f(chars.tail,count+1)
      else if(chars.head == ')') f(chars.tail,count-1)
      else f(chars.tail,count) 

 }  //Type mismatch; found: unit required Boolean
```

Comment: Did you paste-and-copy correctly?  It does not make much sense.

Comment: `balance` expects `Boolean` as a return value, but you only defined `f` and did nothing else in `balance`

Comment: @VictorMoroz You should elaborate on this as an answer below, because it's certainly correct.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18454536/422516) answer, it's exactly the same situation.

Answer (score 1):

`balance` expects `Boolean` as a return value, but you only defined `f` and did nothing else in `balance`. What missing is probably `f(chars, 0)` as the last statement in `balance`.